# Xamarin.IOS MvvmCross App throws NullReference Exception in ViewDidLoad method in iOS9

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, ios9

I am working on an existing Xamarin iOS application with a PCL and uses MvvmCross for IoC and Databinding. Built on MvvmCross 3.1.1

The App looks like a TabControl App but it is buttons on the MainViewCotnroller giving the Tab feel to it. Views are declared in the Storyboard and in the *MainViewController*,

> PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender) method

is overridden to load the selected *"Tab"* View based on the Segue selected - like below

```
  if (segue.Identifier == "FirstSegue")
 {
     var dest = segue.DestinationViewController as FirstView;
     dest.Request = new MvxViewModelRequest<FirstViewModel>(null, null, new MvxRequestedBy());
     foreach (UIView v in src.placeHolderView.Subviews)
     {
         v.RemoveFromSuperview();
     }
     dest.View.Frame = new CGRect(0f, 0f, w, h);
     src.placeHolderView.Add(dest.View);
 }
```

The App runs fine on iPhones with iOS 7.1 till 8.4.

Just before iOS 9 was released I did a test installation for the App on iPhone 6 with iOS 9.1 beta and the App crashed on loading. I retrieved the device logs (below) and analysed that the problem is in the guts of the MvvmCross ViewDidLoad method. I updated the latest SDKs (XCode 7, Xamarin.IOS 9.0) and followed instructions provided by Xamarin and compiled the App again using the latest SDKs same error. Updated the Nuget package reference for MvvmCross to 3.5.1 and still the same issue

The issues is there is a null reference at Line 44 in [the 3.5 MvvMCross Source Code in GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs)

**Note**: This piece of code has not changed since 3.1 at least and 3.5.1 is the latest in the nuget for MvvmCross

Stack Trace below (App Names, Project Names changed for security reasons):

```
   2015-09-21 11:06:26.991 MyApp[1210:60b] Unhandled managed exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve[IMvxViewModelLoader] () [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel (IMvxTouchView touchView) [0x00057] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (IMvxView view, System.Func`1 viewModelLoader) [0x00012] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (IMvxTouchView touchView) [0x00001] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerAdapter.HandleViewDidLoadCalled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise (System.EventH
andler eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00004] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.Views.MvxEventSourceTableViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProject.Touch.MostPurchasedView.ViewDidLoad () [0x00048] in d:\Working\Repo\MyApp\<MyProjectName>\MyProject.Touch\Views\OneOfTheView.cs:31 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00030] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d230615b/source/maccore/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:2632 
  at MyProject.Touch.HomeViewController.PrepareForSegue (UIKit.UIStoryboardSegue segue, Foundation.NSObject sender) [0x0016a] in d:\Working\Repo\MyApp\MyProject.Mobile\MyProject.Touch\HomeViewController.cs:335 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at 
UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d230615b/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:74 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d230615b/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57 
  at MyProject.Touch.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in d:\Working\Repo\MyApp\MyProject.Mobile\MyProject.Touch\Main.cs:16 
2015-09-21 11:06:26.994 MyApp[1210:60b] critical: Stacktrace:
Native stacktrace:
.....
```

I tried the above with just calling the below in the View.cs:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        try
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // throw a toast msg in the UI            
        }
    }
```

I disabled all the *base.ViewDidLoad()* in all the *View.cs* files in the *ViewDidLoad* override methods to take it to the next level and the same problem but inside the constructor of *MvxSimpleTableViewSource* class

Device Log below:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
      at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.TryResolve[IMvxTouchSystem] (IMvxTouchSystem& service) [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.Platform.MvxIosMajorVersionChecker.ReadIsIosVersionOrHigher (Int32 target, Boolean defaultValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.Platform.MvxIosMajorVersionChecker..ctor (Int32 major, Boolean defaultValue) [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.Views.MvxSimpleTableViewSource..ctor (UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.String nibName, System.String cellIdentifier, Foundation.NSBundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at MyProject.Touch.MostPurchasedView.ViewDidLoad () [0x00059] in d:\Working\Repo\MyApp\MyProject.Mobile\MyProject.Touch\Views\OneOfTheView.cs:42 
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (intptr,intptr)
      at UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00030] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d230615b/source/maccore/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:2632 
      at MyProject.Touch.HomeViewController.PrepareForSegue (UIKit.UIStoryboardSegue segue, Foundation.NSObject sender) [0x0016a] in d:\Working\Repo\MyApp\MyProject.Mobile\MyProject.Touch\HomeViewController.cs:343 
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
      at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d230615b/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:74 
      at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d230615b/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57 
      at MyProject.Touch.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in d:\Working\Repo\MyApp\MyProject.Mobile\MyProject.Touch\Main.cs:16
```

**In short :**

Only in iOS 9.1, MvvmCross 3.1.1 AND MvvmCross 3.5.1 has a NullReference Issue in line 44 of the  [*MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods* class which gets called during *ViewDidLoad*](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs)  but works well with iOS 8.4 and below

I am just getting familiar with MvvmCross framework and unsure whether it is an issue with MvvmCross and iOS 9.

Has anyone come across this issue? Any help on this would be appreciated.

**Note**: The MvvmCross samples work fine with iOS9. So I believe it has to be something with the Tab implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is that MvvmCross 3.1.1 not is build for iOS unified code. This will prevent you from submitting your app. MvvmCross 4.0 is currently in beta, but i would recommend using it, because it has many fixes.

If the code crashes on line 44 while trying to resolve `IMvxViewModelLoader`, it probably means that you are missing some package where the `IMvxViewModelLoader` is.

Comment: 3.1.1 is not Unified - True. But 3.5.1 i think is iOS unified code and still does not work. I believe the issue may not be in the unified version. But thanks for the heads up. I will try with 4.0 and will update you. Thanks again for your suggestion.  - Vinod

Comment: Tried with _MvvmCross 4.0 Beta_ and has the same issue. Very much inclined to rewrite it to a proper TabControl using MvvmCross. Will wait and see if there is any positive response on this Question. Thanks

Comment: Could you make a small sample where we could reproduce this, and add an issue to the main repo?

Comment: As you mentioned, Unification was a part of the problem apart from the poor implementation of MVVMCross. Things such as `Mvx.IocConstruct<T>()` instead of `Mvx.Resolve<T>()` , missing `base.PerformBootstrap()` in SetUp.cs etc. were a few to be named. Few References needed version upgrades. After redoing the steps carefully again and changing the way MVVMCross is implemented, the App now builds and runs successfully. Apologies for not getting back sooner on this. I am going to mark your reply as Answer to this as it was part of the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to improve the sample for MvvmCross if possible.